Queries on structural equation model
Can the outcome / dependent variable be made of only one or two items?
Can I merge different scale items say a 5 point & a 7 point likert into a single latent construct?
Also I have a behavioral outcome question which is a 4 point scale - can I merge this with 2 likert scales to create a new latent variable?

I think you need to provide more information for an adequate response.  One answer seems to provide advice that assumes you are calculating a composite from the different scale items, whereas another answer provides advice about using a common-factor model.  It will be helpful if you provide a path diagram of the model you intend to fit, along with a full description of each observed-variable's scale.

You can use items with different numbers of response categories as indicators of a latent variable (factor) in a structural equation model (SEM) using appropriate estimation techniques for ordered categorical (ordinal) variables. These techniques are typically based on polychoric correlations (rather than covariances) and use special estimation methods that are suitable for ordinal data (e.g., WLSMV in Mplus/DWLS in lavaan). Issues of reliability and validity can be assessed as part of the factor model. See
Finney, S. J., & DiStefano, C. (2006). Non-normal and categorical data in structural equation modeling. In G. R. Hancock & R. O. Mueller (Eds.), Structural equation modeling: A second course. Greenwich, CT: Information Age Publishing.
Flora, D. B., & Curran, P. J. (2004). An empirical evaluation of alternative models of estimation for confirmatory factor analysis with ordinal data. Psychological Methods, 9, 466–491.
Jöreskog, K. and Moustaki, I. (2001). Factor analysis for ordinal variables: A comparison of three approaches. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 36, 347-387.
Li, C. H. (2016). The performance of ML, DWLS, and ULS estimation with robust corrections in structural equation models with ordinal variables. Psychological Methods, 21(3), 369-387.
Rhemtulla, M., Brosseau-Liard, P. É., & Savalei, V. (2012). When can categorical variables be treated as continuous? A comparison of robust continuous and categorical SEM estimation methods under suboptimal conditions. Psychological Methods, 17(3), 354-373.
Takane, Y. & De Leeuw, J. (1987). On the relationship between item response theory and factor analysis of discretized variables. Psychometrika, 52, 393-408.
See also:
https://statmodel.com/references.shtml#categorical
